# How to flatten string encoded json with jq?

Tags: jq

Hi I have the following json.

```
[
    {
        "myfield1": "foo",
        "myfield2": "{\"field1\":6366987, \"field2\":5501072}"
    },
    {
        "myfield1": "bar",
        "myfield2": "{\"field1\":123456, \"field2\":123456}"
    }
]
```

And would like to get...

```
[
    {
        "myfield1": "foo",
        "field1": 6366987,
        "field2": 5501072 
    },
    {
        "myfield1": "foo",
        "field1": 123456,
        "field2": 123456 
    },
]
```

So far I got this...

jq '[.[0] | {myfield1: .myfield1, myfield2: .myfield2|fromjson}]'

But this means I have to specify each json field plus it doesn't flatten the json encoded string.

Edit:

I think I got it with this...

jq '[.[0]|with_entries(select(.key != "myfield2"))+(.myfield2|fromjson)]'

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the solution involves `fromjson`, but a simpler, more direct, and more efficient approach would be as follows:

```
map( { myfield1 } + ( .myfield2 | fromjson ) )
```

If you want to retain all the fields except "myfield2", consider:

```
map( del(.myfield2) + ( .myfield2 | fromjson ) )
```

Comment: Cool, I wanted a more generic version. There are more fields then just myfield1. Sorry if it's not specified in the question.

Comment: jq 'map(delpaths([["myfield2"]]) + (.myfield2|fromjson))' works

Answer (score 0):

My trick for making Terraform output, AWS cli output, and AWS logs readable will work here also.

@peak is on the right path with `fromjson` but the use of `map` is very task specific. I suggest using `walk`

```
## Input:
jq 'walk(if type == "string" and .[0:2] == "{\"" then .=(.|fromjson) else . end)'<<EOF
[
    {
        "myfield1": "foo",
        "myfield2": "{\"field1\":6366987, \"field2\":5501072}"
    },
    {
        "myfield1": "bar",
        "myfield2": "{\"field1\":123456, \"field2\":123456}"
    }
]
EOF

## Output:
[
  {
    "myfield1": "foo",
    "myfield2": {
      "field1": 6366987,
      "field2": 5501072
    }
  },
  {
    "myfield1": "bar",
    "myfield2": {
      "field1": 123456,
      "field2": 123456
    }
  }
]
```

This assumes that all embedded JSON is a minified dictionary. You can expand the simple logic if you need to support a list, whitespace, or the full [RFC7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)